# how many non-isomorphic group of order 15 are there?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be group of order $15 = 3 \cdot 5  = p \cdot q$ , where $p < q$ are primes. I know that there exists a unique non abelian group of order $pq$ and one abelian non isomorphic group of order $pq$. I think here are two non isomorphic of order $15$

Am i right or wrong ?

Comment: Can you describe this non-Abelian order $15$ group please?

Comment: I don't see $15$ on [this list](https://oeis.org/A060652)...

Comment: @thanks  alots Arthur

Comment: ok  ,there is no non  abeliean group  of order 15 @ Lord the shark unknown